# TextArea Save/Retrieve from the Database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database, textarea

I am trying to save the data in a TextArea into a column in my database.

Then retrieve the data i saved from the database into a label or div.

Using this in HTMl to save:

```
<textarea runat="server"  id="TextArea1" cols="100" rows="10" ></textarea>
```

Using this in c# to save:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_qualification", TextArea1.InnerText);
```

I dont have any problem saving.

**But when i retrieve the data from the database, the data does not have any linebreaks.**

```
test2.InnerText = myReader3["s_qualification"].ToString();
```

Edit: When i display the data in a text area, it displays fine but its not the way i want it to.. The text needs to displayed like a label as its for a profile page's description

ps: using visual studio 2010, c#

Sorry for the trouble, Everything fixed:

```
test2.InnerHtml = myReader3["s_qualification"].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

I entered the following text into the text box:

This is a test of the line breaks to see if a text area actually include line breaks \n
or is is just a magic word wrapping that happens \n
and it needs to be done manually.

Where \n shows where I pressed the Enter key.

```
var myText = TextArea1.Text;
string newText = myText.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

Results in newText:

This is a test of the line breaks to see if a text area actually include line breaks <br/>or is is just a magic word wrapping that happens <br/>and it needs to be done manually.

So,

```
test2.InnerText = myReader3["s_qualification"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can not detect line breaks at while you visualize on

```
test2.InnerText = myReader3["s_qualification"].ToString();
```

instead you sholud try to visualize on

```
<textarea>your text</textarea>
```

Note: `Jon \n\r Skeet` will be displayed in one line on visual studio watch window but two lines on textarea

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply.. Its working when i retrieve the data onto a textarea. But the text is editable when its inside a text area, which i dont want.. I only need the text to be visble.

Comment: Yea, with that its uneditable, but im trying to snatch the text and display it on something like a profile page, so having that doesnt really go with the flow of the rest... Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: You could ask a new question for that with further explanations.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help... I just figured it out... 

`test2.InnerHtml = myReader3["s_qualification"].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");`

This does everything i need..

Answer (score 0):

Much better approach (if you display text in a label) is this: assign this CSS to your label:

```
label{
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Source:
www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp